# Vue-router. Обмен данными между компонентами маршрутов

Tags: vue.js

Привет всем!

Есть два маршрута.

```
  const routes = [
      {path: "/items",    component: Items},
      {path: "/item/:id", component: OneItem}
  ];
```

В компоненте Items получаю данные от сервера о всех продуктах и вывожу их в виде ссылок. При нажатии на одну из ссылок осуществляется переход на страницу одного продукта, другими словами попадаем в компонент OneItem. Как правильно из компонента OneItem получить уже загруженные данные компонента Items?

Спасибо, всем откликнувшимся!

Comment: можно принимать данные в родительском элементе и иметь доступ к ним через this.$parent.списокПродуктов. Но ето не совсем то что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Для приложений на vue.js существует удобный модуль [VueX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/getting-started.html).
Как его завести лучше почитать по документации.

Но принцип работы будет достаточно прост - в компоненте Items загружаем все данные в хранилище (store). А дальше используем эти данные в любых компонентах.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал следующим образом (может пригодится таким же новичкам, как я):

```
const Item = Vue.component('Item', function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
    // отправляем массив с данными перед изменением маршрута
    beforeDestroy: function() {
        this.$parent.$emit('sendData', this.data);
    },
    ...
);

const OneItem = Vue.component('OneItem', function(resolve, reject) {
    ...
    created: function () {
        let self = this;
        // отписываемся от события, иначе каждый раз их количество будет увеличиваться
        this.$parent.$on('sendData', function(data){
            self.$parent.$off('sendData');
            for( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
                // здесь в цикле ищу данные для нужного товара
            }
         }
    });
});
```

Здесь я использовал $parent, т.к. компоненты глобальные и они ссылаются на главный экземпляр Vue, но можно создать и отдельный экземпляр "шины" и через него передавать данные. Если передача через "шину" предпочтительней, буду благодарен за объяснение.